# How to scrape data from PDF into Excel

Tags: python, excel, pdf, scrape, pdf-scraping

I am trying to scrape the data from PDF and get it saved into an excel file. This is the pdf I needed: https://www.medicaljournals.se/acta/content_files/files/pdf/98/219/Suppl219.pdf

However, I need to scrape not all the data but the following one (below), and then saved it to excel in different cells:
From page 5, starting from **P001** to and including **Introduction** - there is a P number, title, people names, and Introduction.

For now, I can only convert a PDF file into text (my code below) and save it all in one cell, but I need it to be separated into a different cells

```
import PyPDF2 as p2

PDFfile = open('Abstract Book from the 5th World Psoriasis and Psoriatic Arthritis 
Conference 2018.pdf', 'rb')
pdfread = p2.PdfFileReader(PDFfile)

pdflist = []

i = 6
while i<pdfread.getNumPages():
  pageinfo = pdfread.getPage(i)
  #print(pageinfo.extractText())
  i = i + 1

  pdflist.append(pageinfo.extractText().replace('\n', ''))

print(pdflist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main you need is 'header' regex as 15 UPPERcase letters and 'article' regex letter 'P' and 3 digits.
One more regex helps you to divide your text by any of keywords

```
article_re = re.compile(r'[P]\d{3}')  #P001: letter 'P' and 3 digits
header_re = re.compile(r'[A-Z\s\-]{15,}|$')  #min 15 UPPERCASE letters, including '\n' '-' and
key_word_delimeters = ['Peoples', 'Introduction','Objectives','Methods','Results','Conclusions','References']

file = open('data.pdf', 'rb')
pdf = pdf.PdfFileReader(file)

text = ''

for i in range(6, 63):
    text += pdf.getPage(i).extractText()  # all text in one variable

articles = []

for article in re.split(article_re, text):
    header = re.match(header_re, article)  # recieving a match
    other_text = re.split(header_re, article)[1]  # recieving other text
    if header:
        header = header.group()            # get text from match
        item = {'header': header}
        first_name_letter = header[-1]     # save the first letter of name to put it in right position. Some kind of HOT BUGFIX
        header = header[:-1]               # cut last character: the first letter of name
        header = header.replace('\n', '')  #delete linebreakers
        header = header.replace('-', '')   #delete line break symbol
        other_text = first_name_letter + other_text
        data_array = re.split(
            'Introduction:|Objectives:|Methods:|Results:|Conclusions:|References:',
            other_text)

        for key, data in zip(key_word_delimeters, data_array):
            item[key] = data.replace('\n', '')
        articles.append(item)
```